# How to make a <Select> tag that can display color option?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to make a color option like below using React JS but I cannot find a solution for it.

[image]

Any solution to achieve like the picture above would be appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using JavaScript and by some proper styling.

```js
function selectColor()
{ 
var color = document.getElementById('colours').value;
document.getElementById("text1").style.backgroundColor = color;


}
```

```css
#text1{ display: inline-block; width: 20px; height: 20px;  }
```

```html
<h3 >Text Colour: 

    <select id="colours" onchange="selectColor();">
      <option value="None"></option>
      <option value="red">Red</option>
      <option value="green">Green</option>
      <option value="blue">Blue</option>
      <option value="pink">Pink</option>
    </select>
    <div id="text1"></div>
    
  </h3>
```